# ChartJS 3.8.2: Avoid hiding Y axis ticks when chart shrinks

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying to force my chart to use a `stepSize` of 5 on my `y` axis. The problem is, when that chart shrink's (browser window get's resized or whatever) the ticks use a `stepSize` of 15. Can I force te chart to use steps of 5 whatever it's canvas size is?

This are my `options`:

```
options: {
    scales: {
        y: {
            grid: {
                color: ({ tick }) => tick.value == 0 ? 'black' : Chart.defaults.borderColor
            },
            min: -60,
            ticks: {
                stepSize: 5, // <- this works only when the chart is big enough
                display: true
            }
        }
    },
    layout: {
        padding: {
            right: 10,
            top: 10,
        }
    }
}
```

But this is what I get:
[ticks are using a stepSize of 15](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSuLR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define `options.scales.y.ticks.autoSkip: false` as follows:

```
scales: {
  y: {   
     ticks: {
       stepSize: 5,
       autoSkip: false
     }
  }
```

The default value of `autoSkip` is `true`.

> *If `true`, automatically calculates how many labels can be shown and hides labels accordingly (...). Turn `autoSkip` off to show all labels
> no matter what.*

For further information, please take a look at [Common tick options to all cartesian axes](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/#common-tick-options-to-all-cartesian-axes) from the Chart.js documentation.